# How to make work ConfigSection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing a serious issue here, I'm trying to configure a new section for my web app and after trying 10 thousands different things I think it's better if I make my own post.

**Here is my code :**

```xml
<configSections>    
  <section name="EmailConfigurationSection"
           type="ServiceEmail.Helper.EmailConfigurationSection, ServiceEmail.Helper,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>   
</configSections>

<EmailConfigurationSection isDebug="true" 
  smtpAddress="***" 
  smtpLogin="***" 
  smtpPassword="***" 
  smtpPort="***" 
  emailPersonForTest="***@***.lu"/>
```

```cs
public class EmailConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static readonly EmailConfigurationSection settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("EmailConfigurationSection") as EmailConfigurationSection;

    public static EmailConfigurationSection EmailConfiguration
    {
        get { return settings; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("isDebug", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = false)]
    public Boolean IsDebug
    {
        get { return (Boolean) this["isDebug"]; }
        set { this["isDebug"] = value; }
    }
}
```

... I have here all the property defined in my web.config

Everytime I tried to access a property, I got a `NullReferenceException` on EmailConfiguration

I already set my web.conf for it to be copied in the output directory.

After using NameCollectionValue I get that :

```
Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'ServiceEmail.Helper.EmailConfigurationSection'. --System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création du gestionnaire de section de configuration pour EmailConfigurationSection : Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'ServiceEmail.Helper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Service_Mails\web.config line 8) ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'ServiceEmail.Helper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
   à System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
   à System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   à System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   à System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   à System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   à System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   à ServiceEmail.Helper.EmailConfigurationSection..cctor() dans C:\Users\***\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ServiceEmail\ServiceEmail\Helper\EmailConfigurationSection.cs:ligne 14 --ServiceEmail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update :**

From your edit, it seems you have an error in your type attribute. Make sure the dll name is really `ServiceEmail.Helper.dll`. It might just be `ServiceEmail.dll`

---

You may be trying to initialize your settings too early.

Maybe you can try to replace

```
private static readonly EmailConfigurationSection settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("EmailConfigurationSection") as EmailConfigurationSection;

public static EmailConfigurationSection EmailConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        return settings;
    }
}
```

with :

```
public static EmailConfigurationSection EmailConfiguration
{
    get
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("EmailConfigurationSection") as EmailConfigurationSection;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Greenarrow from your edit, it seems that you have an error in your type attribute. Sure that the dll name is ServiceEmail.Helper.dll, not just ServiceEmail.dll ?

Comment: Now I got an Invalid cast between my custom section and the nameValue collection I tried before, I cleaning up my code and tell you if it's ok ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot it's finally working, I still think I had an other error before cause I've changed my assembly name this morning cause I was desperate. please make your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with following ?

```
EmailConfigurationSectionloc = 
   (EmailConfigurationSection)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("EmailConfigurationSection");
```

Comment: Could please check with  in-built NameValueCollection like this.              NameValueCollection objEmail =    (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("EmailConfigurationSection");

Comment: I just did it, I made an edit you can see what I get